# SimpleHTMLDom iteration through table

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I am using SimpleHTMLDOM to get information from my school roster. The problem is that the table structure is pretty hard to parse and I am looking for some help.

The table looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/xg3mRAHw

The code looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/gWW7WyDA

The result looks like this (also included how I want the result to look like!):

Current format:

```
array
  3 =>
    array
      '28-11-2011' =>
        array
          0 => string '08.45-10.30 ' (length=12)
          1 => string 'CMD-1 HC interaction design' (length=27)
          2 => string 'CMD-1vt-p2.01 - CMD-1vt-p2.18 ' (length=30)
          3 => string 'OVk45' (length=5)
          4 => string 'J.P. van Leeuwen' (length=16)
          5 => string '10.30-12.15 ' (length=12)
          6 => string 'CMD-1 Training samenwerken' (length=26)
          7 => string 'CMD-1vt-p2.09 - CMD-1vt-p2.10 ' (length=30)
          8 => string 'SL433' (length=5)
          9 => string 'B. Hartman' (length=10)
```

Wanted format:

```
array
  3 =>
    array
      '28-11-2011' =>
        array
          0 =>
            array
              'time' => string '08.45-10.30 ' (length=12)
              'name' => string 'CMD-1 HC interaction design' (length=27)
              'group' => string 'CMD-1vt-p2.01 - CMD-1vt-p2.18 ' (length=30)
              'place' => string 'OVk45' (length=5)
              'teacher' => string 'J.P. van Leeuwen' (length=16)
          1 =>
            array
              'time' => string '10.30-12.15 ' (length=12)
              'name' => string 'CMD-1 Training samenwerken' (length=26)
              'group' => string 'CMD-1vt-p2.09 - CMD-1vt-p2.10 ' (length=30)
              'place' => string 'SL433' (length=5)
              'teacher' => string 'B. Hartman' (length=10)
```

The problem is that I do not understand how I can get to this result using (only) SimpleHTMLDOM. I am sure that I'm missing something here because I'm close to the final markup of the array. The last step to have it actually show up like the future example is something I cannot get to work.

Could someone give me a few tips on how to proceed and get the array like the way I want it to? I have been looking at XSL too but that is far too complicated for me at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to segment the tr array as well.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($table as $tr) {
...
   $output[$info['week']][$info['date']][$count] = array();
   $count++;
...
$output[$info['week']][$info['date']][$count][] = $td->innertext;
```

Now as for the 'time', 'name', 'group' etc. values, I don't see those anywhere in the xml, so I guess you will just have to maintain an inner count when appending `td->innertext`.

Comment: I have managed to get the result somewhat how I wanted but I am forced to look for a different way to parse the HTML document. This is the table example (data replaced) that I somehow need to parse: http://pastebin.com/zNu7iTTJ SimpleHTMLDom does not seem to be able to parse this correctly and do the trick for me it seems.